# jQuery Show Animation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I'm working on a site and using Bootstrap and jQuery.

It's kind of impossible to explain my problem in words, so I've uploaded a gif showing my problem: [Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba0jX.gif)

**I've created a fiddle as well: [JFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BY7H4/)**

Basically, that error alert box is a Bootstrap template and I am trying to animate it using jQuery's `show('shake');` but the problem is, there seems to be some problem with the animation, the div only expand for the text AFTER the animation.

These are my codes for it:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="errorBox" style="display:none; padding:15px;">
</div>
```

-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#signIn').submit(function (e) {
                if ($('#tbxUsername').val().length == 0) {
                    $('#errorBox').html('<strong>Error:</strong> You need to enter your username!');
                    $('#errorBox').hide().show('shake');
                    return false;
                } else if ($('#tbxPassword').val().length == 0) {
                    $('#errorBox').html('<strong>Error:</strong> You need to enter your password!');
                    $('#errorBox').hide().show('shake');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Just did, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/BY7H4/
It demonstrates my problem exactly.

Comment: Did you set with and height or only padding?

Comment: I didn't touch any width and height settings, twitter bootstrap's alert default, not sure if it sets any width or height.

Comment: I think it's more of a problem with the padding/margin, shake seems to change it http://jsfiddle.net/BY7H4/1/

Answer (score 2):

`shake` is not part of jquery core. You'll need to download it form `jquery-ui` effects, to use it in your code.

Natively, only fading and sliding is supported.

### After edit:

It seems a bug. You can workaround that by adding `style="min-height:55px;"` to your `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BY7H4/2/)

Comment: I do have jQuery UI installed:
"<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>"